# Is it possible to fire a browser's about window with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, internet-explorer-6

Well the title explains my whole question. What i want to archive, is a revolutionary 'upgrade' button, that when you press it, the browser's native 'update' window pops up. If it is not present, then it create's an fake update window, so that users can update the browser.

I do not longer want to support the old IE6 browser. I want to force my users to upgrade their browser as it is insane to support a 10 year old browser.

Comment: I don't really believe this is possible.  You're better off implementing the code found here: http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Why not just hire a guy in a trenchcoat, give him a ball peen hammer, and ask him to take knees out? There are times when folk don't have a choice to upgrade, or really just don't care.

Comment: If they dont care about upgrading... just because they dont 'care'.. well then i dont care about them. They must see consequences from their ignorant behavior then. 

As i stated on a comment below; as long as we keep supporting IE6, the IT managers of the companies that control the software will say 'it works right, why upgrading'. If more and more websites stop working on IE6 they have to upgrade their client computers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to get remove support for IE 6, I suggest visiting Microsof't website dedicated to the cause

http://www.ie6countdown.com/

The site contains instructions on how to place a banner on your site advising IE 6 users that they are using a very out of date browser.

http://www.ie6countdown.com/join-us.html

It informs them how to upgrade.

Comment: Aah, looks like this is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no way to do this from within JavaScript. Luckily!

> I want to force my users to upgrade their browser as it is insane to support a 10 year old browser.

Fortunately, that is not possible. You could redirect users to their respective browser's upgrade page; however, I would consider that very impolite. It's not our business to force people to do anything; if your site doesn't support a specific browser, simply don't display it.

In the case of IE6, it might be justified to link to the IE6 countdown page, but consider that a lot of users have no control over what browser they use.

Comment: ... Other than detecting the browser version (with conditionals) and just denying them access to the site. Remember the days when it was the other way around?

Comment: Well, as long as we (developers) keep supporting IE6, the IT managers of all these companies (you probably point that way with 'no control') will say.. why upgrade? it works ok right?

Comment: @Nique there's no need to *support* IE6. But shoving an upgrade dialog in users' faces is terribly arrogant, and is bound to drive away users. Especially those who can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. You'll be better off creating your own dialog box (which looks like the IE About box) otherwise spam pages would eat our head with popping up the about dialog all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

It's a huge security breach to allow JavaScript to install arbitrary software. If you don't want to support IE6, don't, eventually the web will break for these users and they will be forced to upgrade, but what do you think gives you the right to dictate what software users should use?

Comment: Well, i have the right to force my users to upgrade as the old software they use, breaks my application. I do not want to support (Develop) it longer as it eats 70% of my time. It is upgrade (it is free !@#) or suffer the consequences.. in my opinion.

Comment: Just state that you don't support IE6 and they are using it at their own risk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IE Conditionals](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = '404.html';
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

If they can't get to your website, they're not exactly a user of your website, correct?

Just keep in mind it used to be the other way around. It's better to be nice and warn them they may have a poor experience, than try to take over their computer. :)